# Does the Kenwood TH-D74 support Access Point and Terminal mode for D-Star?

Tags: kenwood, icom, d-star, kenwood-th-d74

Does the Kenwood TH-D74 support Access Point and Terminal mode for D-Star like the Icom ID-51 PLUS2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ICOM gateway terminal mode is a unique mode. It allows you to configure the radio to use the radio, tethered to a computer through a USB cable, to route the communications through the computer, out to the Internet, to access a remote gateway. In this mode, the RF signal of the radio is not a factor since all communications are actually going through the tethered computer and the Internet. The intended use of this mode is when you cannot access a local repeater with an appropriate gateway.

[image]

The ICOM Gateway Access Point mode allows you to use another D-Star transceiver, connected to the Internet, to access a remote gateway. In this case, the RF connection is used:

[image]

The TH-D74 supports traditional gateway settings but in its case, the gateway must be attached to the repeater that you are communicating with through the local RF connection. There is no native option to make a gateway connection through the Internet without the use of a local repeater.

You may, however, be able to closely emulate the Icom Gateway Access Point function through the use of a local gateway device such as this OpenSpot device:

[image]

You can then use your radio without tethering to access a remote Gateway/repeater without going through a local repeater:

[image]

Comment: What does "unique" mean here? I feel it has more meaning than just what the dictionary says.

Comment: I simply meant that I am not aware of any other D-Star radios that have that feature. No hidden meaning.

Comment: I see. The manual actually mentions those two modes as Unique functions, so, I was wondering.

Answer (score 1):

No. The D-74 cannot act as an access point/gateway.